# Balance the Equation

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Peter found an old piece of paper that an equation was written on it. Some of **digits** or **operations** are unreadable. Help Peter to complete the **balanced** equation.

[image]

The equation is: $87+?3?12-4?2=?36-15??1/?$

Source: My Brain

Comment: Cut the piece of paper in a perfect half, weigh each half, it's a now perfectly balanced equation!

Comment: Am I right? Lol

Comment: problem is that peter have no balance or scale :)

Comment: I really liked my solution though! It IS equally balanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one more solution I found:

> $87+33*12-482 = 136-15*81/9$

Comment: The exact solution that I expected.

Answer (score 4):

87+63-12-4*2=136−15+81/9

There are probably many possible solutions.

Comment: You right, there is at least one more solution. +1

Answer (score -4):

Runs to the nearest store, buys a scale.

Cut the piece of paper in a perfect half, weigh each half, it's a now perfectly balanced equation!

+1 for originality?

Comment: actually a -1 for off-topic answer. Despite comments, answers should not contain jokes. (just my opinion)

Comment: It does work though...

Comment: Again, **IF** you have the right tool to measure weight. Something that question said nothing about.

Comment: @Rafe See my edit.

Comment: hah, funny! Please read question carefully. **"Help Peter to complete the balanced equation."**

Comment: Fine... Still original, please take back the -1 lol

Comment: I would downvote if I had the rep.   It doesn't help anyone to answer a puzzle question with play of words.   In fact it's not even a good play on words.   If you cut a piece of paper in half and put it on a balance, it isn't a "balanced equation".   It's a balance with two scraps of paper on it, each of which has a random sequence of numbers and symbols.

Comment: I was thinking outside the box.

Comment: $(+1)$ for originality :P